# Notification on IIS memory recyle

Tags: iis, monitoring, iis-6

I've enabled memory recycling upon maximum used memory in IIS for an application pool.  I'd like to receive a notification when a recycle happens.  How can I do this?  We're on Win2k3 using IIS V6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I'm aware of to do this would be to use a tool to monitor the event log on the server computer and fire off an email when the recycle event occurs.

You'll need to be sure that recycle logging is turned on. The procedure to turn that on, and the various event ids associated with application pool recylces are described in this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332088

Such a script could actually run as a Windows service, and wouldn't be too bad to code up in VBscript. If you've already got some kind of "enterprise" event log monitoring solution, use that. If not, consider scripting it. (Maybe if I have some free time this afternoon I'll code something up... we'll see...)

Comment: Thanks - found that it was enabled and just need to set up the alert.  Thanks

Comment: Ended up using Splunk for the alerting.  Splunk is great.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

1. Configure IIS that the application pool recycle [is logged to the Windows event log](http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=17)
2. Send emails depending on event log entries (see [here for an example](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/dotnet/soa/Send-email-alerts-when-errors-are-written-to-the-event-log/0,339028399,339292231,00.htm) - .NET implementation)